# How to sort a boolean column in antd table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

In my [antd](https://ant.design/components/table/) table , one of the column is boolean. I want to sort that column. How to do that?

```
sorter: (a, b) => a.isPayment.localeCompare(b.isPayment),
render: (val)=><div className="text_overlap">{val ? 'Yes':'No'}</div>
```

I guess `localeCompare` works only for string.

Comment: What's the value of that boolean column represented in your code? I assume they only have 2 values so localCompare works just fine.

Comment: `true` and `false` . If true dispaly Yes , else displays No in the column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript we have:

```js
true - false === 1
false - true === -1
```

So all you have to do is just subtracting booleans in your sorter function.

```js
sorter: (a, b) => a - b
```

Comment: This worked with a syntax change
`sorter: (a, b) => a.isPayment - b.isPayment,`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a error message "The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type." was shown in my VSCode.

Here is my solution.

```js
sorter: (a, b) => Number(a.isPayment) - Number(b.isPayment),
```